# Can I damage my Sony a6300 sensor if the sun is in my photo?

Tags: sony-alpha, sun

I took a few photos this weekend of a mountain range, and the sun was up above them, off to the top right for most of the photos. I was taking these photos (moving the angle around and whatnot) for about 5 minutes in total. Would this damage the sensor, or is it more like "don't aim the camera directly at the sun"?

Comment: The question marked above as a duplicate specifies *where the sun appears*. That is, at sunrise - when the light and heat from the sun is passing through much more of the Earth's atmosphere than when it is high in the sky.

Comment: @MichaelClark I don't read it that way. I think that means "Where the sun appears in the photo."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will most probably not damage the camera. However if you are taking a long time composing your shots, always having the sun in the frame, the effect of magnification that the lens has can cause damage to the sensor as the temperature would rise. Using a long lens pointed directly at the sun is also dangerous even for shorter periods. Shooting the sunrise or sunset is not a problem.

Comment: this answer couldn't be more false

Comment: Why is this wrong? He is taking landscape photos, the sun is in the frame but it is not magnified, it is equivalent as watching the sky on a sunny day. Using a lens with a great magnification and pointing it directly at the sun can indeed cause a temperature raise and even a burn of the sensor.

Comment: your original comment was 100% false. Go stare at the sun for 1 minute.

Comment: Maybe the parallel was not clear, I was trying to compare to the case when you look at the sky or over a landscape and you also see the sun, I have updated the answer to make it more undersyandable

Comment: I think it could be far more false, actually..